# Airflow Memory Error: Task exited with return code -9

Tags: mongodb, docker, memory, airflow

According to both of these [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57365204/why-is-airflow-crashing-with-info-task-exited-with-return-code-9) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794860/airflow-kills-my-tasks-after-1-minute), my Airflow DAG run is returning the error `INFO - Task exited with return code -9` due to an out-of-memory issue. My DAG run has 10 tasks/operators, and each task simply:

1. makes a query to get one of my BigQuery tables, and
2. writes the results to a collection in my Mongo database.

The size of the 10 BigQuery tables range from 1MB to 400MB, and the total size of all 10 tables is ~1GB. My docker container has default 2GB of memory and I've increased this to 4GB, however I am still receiving this error from a few of the tasks. I am confused about this, as 4GB should be plenty of memory for this. I am also concerned because, in the future, these tables may become larger (a single table query could be 1-2GB), and I'd like to avoid these `return code -9` errors at that time.

I'm not quite sure how to handle this issue, since the point of the DAG is to transfer data from BigQuery to Mongo daily, and the queries / data in-memory for the DAG's tasks is necessarily fairly large then, based on the size of the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the error message you get corresponds to an out of memory issue.

Referring to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags?hl=sr#common_issues):

> DAG execution is RAM limited. Each task execution starts with two
>   Airflow processes: task execution and monitoring. Currently, each node
>   can take up to 6 concurrent tasks. More memory can be consumed,
>   depending on the size of the DAG.

High memory pressure in any of the GKE nodes will lead the Kubernetes scheduler to evict pods from nodes in an attempt to relieve that pressure. While many different Airflow components are running within GKE, most don't tend to use much memory, so the case that happens most frequently is that a user uploaded a resource-intensive DAG. The Airflow workers run those DAGs, run out of resources, and then get evicted.

You can check it with following steps:

1. In the Cloud Console, navigate to `Kubernetes Engine` -> `Workloads`
2. Click on `airflow-worker`, and look under `Managed pods`
3. If there are pods that show `Evicted`, click each evicted pod and look for the `The node was low on resource: memory` message at the top of the window.

What are the possible ways to fix OOM issue?

- Create a new Cloud Composer environment with a larger machine type than the current machine type.
- Ensure that the tasks in the DAG are [idempotent](https://medium.com/handy-tech/airflow-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls-9ba53fba14eb), which means that the result of running the same DAG run multiple times should be the same as the result of running it once.
- Configure [task retries](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#module-airflow.models) by setting the number of retries on the task - this way when your task gets `-9'ed` by the scheduler it will go to `up_for_retry` instead of `failed`

Additionally you can check the behavior of CPU:

1. In the Cloud Console, navigate to `Kubernetes Engine` -> `Clusters`
2. Locate `Node Pools` at the bottom of the page, and expand the `default-pool` section
3. Click the link listed under `Instance groups`
4. Switch to the `Monitoring` tab, where you can find `CPU utilization`

Ideally, the GCE instances shouldn't be running over 70% CPU at all times, or the Composer environment may become unstable during resource usage.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not running Airflow on GKE or with Cloud Composer currently, just locally, however this is still helpful.

Comment: I was assuming that you are using Cloud Composer since you mentioned BigQuery. I'm sorry for misunderstanding. But the point with possible ways to fix OOM issue is still applicable to your case. I also recommend you to check Apache Airflow [forum](https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow?at=59e5bd23f7299e8f53f8d667) where you can find discussion about OOM and Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060390/airflow-scheduler-out-of-memory-problems). More than that I recommend you to give a try for Cloud Composer. It has many features, which allows you to omit such problems

Answer (score 1):

I am going to chunk the data so that less is loaded into any 1 task at any given time. I'm not sure yet whether I will need to use GCS/S3 for intermediary storage.